# is it possible to get changing data from with js puppeteer without reloading a website?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to get live changing data from external website with js puppeteer. Is it possible without reloading this external website evertime?

Comment: Depends on the site. Most sites use ajax or sockets (or many other methods, actually) to send and receieve data from a server without page reloads. Puppeteer is designed to be able to extract data from the page in real time, just as you do when you browse it by hand. Please provide more info about which site you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example that logs "Births today" from https://www.worldometers.info/ in real time using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (another possible option is monitoring page network activity, but this option usually requires more site analysing; this site seems not using network activity and updates its data with pure JS according to some statistics):

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://www.worldometers.info/');

  await page.waitForSelector('#c3 span.counter-number');

  await page.exposeFunction('logInPuppeteer', (birthsNumber) => {
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
    process.stdout.clearLine(0);
    process.stdout.write(`Births today: ${birthsNumber}.`);
  });

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const target = document.querySelector('#c3 span.counter-number');
    const config = { characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
       window.logInPuppeteer(target.innerText);
    });
    observer.observe(target, config);
  });
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```